# SQL : get related attribute

Tags: sql

I got following table `devicereplacement` in SQL with 3 columns:

```
id, new_device_id, old_device_id
```

There is also a `device` table with `id`, `mac_address` and etc

I have the following query:

```
select dd.mac_address
from devicereplacement as ddr
inner join devices_device dd on ddr.new_device_id = dd.id
where dd.mac_address = '58155',
```

where I get the new device attributes. Now instead of the new device attributes I want the related old device attributes in my select. I think this should be done with subquery, but I can't get it fixed, it's quite a while since I did those SQL queries.

What I want: the mac address from the old device where the mac_address from new device == x

Comment: Am I missing something, or is what you are looking for accomplished by simply replacing this: `on ddr.new_device_id = dd.id` with this: `on ddr.old_device_id = dd.id`?

You of course would have to add the desired attributes to your `SELECT`

Comment: @SchmitzIT I agree too ut then I have see that OP is selecting dd.mac_address and also has in his where clause this : where dd.mac_address = '58155' ... that makes me think that this query is not what he wants at all...

Comment: I also need the new_device in the where statement to check the mac_address. So I need the ddr.new_device_id = dd.id

Answer (score 1):

Add another join to the same device table

```
select ddo.mac_address
from devicereplacement as ddr
inner join devices_device ddn on ddr.new_device_id = ddn.id
inner join devices_device ddo on ddr.old_device_id = ddo.id
where ddn.mac_address = '58155';
```